# Excel compare sheets find value & replace value, same row - different cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way, Example:
Value 123 lives in cell A1 on sheet1
I need to find value 123 on sheet2 leave value alone but replace another cell with a set value based on what row 123 was found.

Hoping it could work like this:

123(A1 sheet1) 123 found on sheet2 in cell H13 replace A13 on sheet2 with ABC

456(A2 sheet1) 456 found on sheet2 in cell H28 replace A28 on sheet2 with ABC

Thanks so much!

Comment: I think this article should be useful: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/02/25/compare-two-excel-files-sheets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Sheet1` like:

[image]

and `Sheet2` like:

[image]

Running this VBA macro:

```
Sub EasyAsABC()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, FoundIt As Range
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        Set FoundIt = s2.Range("H:H").Find(what:=s1.Cells(i, 1).Value, after:=s2.Range("H1"), lookat:=xlWhole)
        If FoundIt Is Nothing Then
        Else
            s2.Cells(FoundIt.Row, 1).Value = "ABC"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Will produce:

[image]

Comment: Amazing work my friend. Thanks so much fine sir!